# include images programmatically in .md document from within R chunk using knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I want to programmatically include a lot of images in my .Rmd markdown document. Something like

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
cat("![](myfile_1.png)")
```
````

will not work, as the resulting `.md` output is

````
```
## ![](myfile_1.png)
```
````

I would need to get rid of the code tags ```` ``` ```` and the leading `##`.
Is there an option to directly inject markdown code from within the R chunk?

BTY: The same issue applies to HTML as well. Here also a HTML code injection from within an R chunk would be really helpful.

Comment: the answer by @mnel is correct, but I'm wondering why you have to do this; normally I dislike `cat()`s. I can understand it if your images are from outside, otherwise you should just let `knitr` write the images generated from R code to markdown output

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using `results ='asis'` means that you don't have to mess with the hooks, comments etc as the results are not considered code, but markdown (or whatever the output format happens to be)

````
```{r myfile-1-plot, echo = F, results = 'asis'}
cat('\n![This is myfile_1.png](myfile1.png)\n')
```
````

Will result in

```
![This is myfile_1.png](myfile1.png)
```

Note that I wrapped the output text with new line markers to ensure that it is on  a separate line.

Comment: +1 this is absolutely the correct way to go and exactly what `results='asis'` means (http://yihui.name/knitr/options)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you use `knitr`, you could use the `comment` option:

````
```{r echo=FALSE, comment=""}
cat("![](myfile_1.png)")
```
````

### Edit

You will have to change the hooks:

````
```{r echo=FALSE, comment=""}
knit_hooks$set(output = function(x,
        options) x)
cat("![](myfile_1.png)")
```
````

When you want to render markdown again, make sure to reset your hooks again, one way would be to use `render_markdown()`.

````
```{r b, echo=FALSE, comment=""}
render_markdown()
a <- 1
```
````

Comment: Thanks. This solves the part for the `##`. The image will not be included though as we still do not get rid of the `.md` code markups  ```  by this...

Comment: You will need to change the hooks, I changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

To use in a loop, if you need to paste a bunch of pictures from a data frame:

```
for(h in 1:nrow(file_names)){
   image_file<-paste('\n![](', file_names[h],')\n',sep="") 
   cat('\n')
   cat(image_file)
   cat('\n')
}
```

Comment: thanks, I was looking to fix this and you made it work